# Get visible part of UIImageView as UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

In my app, I'm trying to implement a crop feature. So now I need to convert UIImageView's visible part to UIImage.
Here's a screenshot from the UI debugger.

[image]

I've tried to achieve it with this function, but it doesn't work.

```
func imageFromImageView(imageView: UIImageView)  -> UIImage? {
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.rotate(by: 2 * .pi)
    
    imageView.layer.render(in: context)
    
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: What are your "ImageView" settings for "setClipsToBounds " and " contentMode" ?

Comment: imageView.ClipsToBounds = true, contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

Comment: note that 2 pi rotation does nothing

Comment: @PtitXav Yep, I was assuming it. I've found that code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120814/ios-get-visible-portion-of-image-for-an-uiimageview .

Comment: try the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288197/7214847

Comment: @Tadreik Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: So what is the result for the current code you have? Does it return the image for entire imageView?

Comment: @SamB Yep, it's returning the same image with low quality.

Comment: How do you define the area to be cropped? Do you have some sort of a crop rectangle?

Comment: May be outdated but it can explain you : [crip uiimageview to uiimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720720/how-to-crop-a-uiimageview-to-a-new-uiimage-in-aspect-fill-mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bellow extension:

```
private var rendererKey: UInt8 = 0
extension UIView {
    var renderer: UIGraphicsImageRenderer! {
         get {
             guard let rendererInstance = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &rendererKey) as? UIGraphicsImageRenderer else {
                self.renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
                return self.renderer
             }
             return rendererInstance
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &rendererKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
    func snapImageView() -> UIImageView {
        let img:UIImage = renderer.image { ctx in
         DispatchQueue.main.async { 
              layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
          }
        }
        let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: img)
        imageView.frame = renderer.format.bounds
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }
}
// Generate image and image view of any view instance
let anImageView = yourView.snapImageView()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. There is no image.

Comment: You can create it by   yourImageView.snapImageView()

Comment: Yep. I've done it, but when I'm trying to upload that imageView's image property to my backend, it is showing an empty photo.

Comment: Store it locally then upload